# Button automatically enables/disables when input is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable/enable a button based on one input. It's simple, if the input is "", disable the button, otherwise, enable it.

```
 $('#searchBarTextbox').on('change', function () {
             if ($('#searchBarTextbox').val() !== "") {
            $('#btnSearchOk').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#btnSearchOk').prop('disabled', true);
            }
});
```

This works ok, but it enables/disables the button only after the user has clicked outside the text box. Is it possible to have button disable/enable while user is writing in the text box not having them move outside. Can I bind on keyup event maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `input` event for doing this,

```
$('#searchBarTextbox').on('input', function () {
 $('#btnSearchOk').prop('disabled', $.trim($('#searchBarTextbox').val()) === "");
});
```

Comment: Haven't used jQuery in a while but I never knew this one existed!

Answer (score 1):

Try using **keyup** instead of **change**

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hYSku/)**

```
 $('#searchBarTextbox').keyup(function () {
     if ($('#searchBarTextbox').val() !== "") {
        $('#btnSearchOk').prop('disabled', false);
     } else {
        $('#btnSearchOk').prop('disabled', true);
     }
});
```

Comment: @upvoter: key up will get fired unnecessarily even it would even get fired for ctrl key, But input event does not behave like that..

Comment: Key up keeps track of all actions happening on the keyboard. So it does the work for what the OP wants :)